# How to compute the expected distance to the nearest neighbor of higher density (normal distribution)?

Tags: probability, geometry, geometric-probability

Suppose we have $X_1, \dots, X_n$ independent random variables with distribution $N(0, 1)$. The density function is:

\begin{equation}
\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}
\end{equation}

Suppose we have a fixed value $x > 0$. I want to compute the expected value of:
\begin{equation}
Y(x) = \min_{i \in [1, n]\; \phi(X_i) > \phi(x)} \left| x - X_i \right|
\end{equation}
which represents the distance to the nearest neighbor of higher density. $Y$ is a non-negative random variable. For any $t \in [0, 2x]$, the probability that $Y$ exceeds $t$ equals the probability that any $X_i$, such that $\phi(X_i) > \phi(x)$, lies inside $\left[-x, +x-t \right]$, hence:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Y(x) < t) &= 1 - \prod_{i \in [1, n]\; \phi(X_i) > \phi(x)}\mathbb{P}(X_i \in [-x, +x-t] | X_i \in [-x, +x])\\
&= 1 - \left( \frac{1}{A} \int_{-x}^{+x-t} \phi(u)\, du \right)^{nA}
\end{align}
where $A = \int_{-x}^{+x} \phi(u)\,du$. The previous line gives the CDF of $Y(x)$. By differentiating this expression with respect to $t$ with the help of the fundamental theorem of calculus, I am able to recover the PDF of $Y(x)$:
\begin{equation}
f_Y(t)=n\cdot\phi(x-t)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{A}\int_{-x}^{+x-t}\phi(u)\,du\right)^{nA-1}\cdot1_{t\in[0, 2x]}
\end{equation}
Now I want to compute the mean of this PDF, $\mu_Y(x) = \int_0^{2x}tf_Y(t)\,dt$, and ideally find a relation between $\mu_Y(x)$ and $\phi(x)$. However I don't know how to integrate this PDF because of the term which looks like the Gauss error function.

How can I estimate this mean?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you guarantee with probability $1$ that $Y(x)$ exists?  I would have thought that given any particular $x$ there would be a positive probability that $\phi(X_i) \lt \phi(x)$ for all the $X_i$

Comment: $\int\limits_{-x}^{+x-t}\phi(u)\,du = \Phi(x-t) - \Phi(-x) = \Phi(x-t) + \Phi(x) -1$ but I doubt you can go much further

Comment: Thank you for your comments. You're right! I didn't define $Y(x)$ correctly. In fact, $Y(x) = +\infty$ if $\max_{i \in [1, n]} \phi(X_i) < \phi(x)$. In this case, $\mathbb{P}(Y(x) < t) = \mathbb{P}(Y(x) < t \, | \, \max_{i \in [1, n]} \phi(X_i) > \phi(x))$.

Comment: What is $\Phi$ referring to? Why do you think it is not possible to go further?